# text to pdf conversion in android

Tags: java, android-ndk

i want to convert the user given information in text to PDF in Android? I already used iTEXT jar file to convert it but not working in Android SDK?

Comment: Not so sure why its not working with android - but I want to warn you, iText is not a free api... Also posting code is always good way to get a good answer

Comment: Some description of what exactly you are trying and what errors you are getting would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [Google Drive](https://developers.google.com/drive/integrate-android-ui)! Your application can upload the text file and download the PDF. Bonus #1: GDrive can convert many other formats! Bonus #2: the files are backed up on the cloud!